# how hadoop directory differ from hadoop-x.x.x

Tags: hadoop

I am new to hadoop and recently when I was running MapReduce jobs on Openstack hadoop cluster and cd into directory on a datanode machine, I found there are two hadoop folders one is called "hadoop" while the other named"hadoop-2.7.1". Obviously, the latter one makes more sense as it tells the hadoop version. The two folder contains same sub-directories, but how these two differ from each other? What if I'd like to disable HDFS permission checking on this machine, which one should I go?

**Here is a screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you add that screenshot directly to your post, as code ?

Comment: Thanks Rahul for editing. Also, thank you for reminder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As colors in the screenshot suggest, `hadoop` is not a separate directory but is just a symbolic link, obviously pointing to `hadoop-2.7.1`. Run `ls -l` to check this.

You should cd into `hadoop` directory. It exists intentionally to avoid writing hadoop version explicitly. When new version of hadoop is deployed, a new versioned directory will be created, and `hadoop` symbolic link will be changed to point to the latest versioned directory. Like this:

```
hadoop-2.7.1
hadoop-2.7.2
hadoop-2.7.3
hadoop -> hadoop-2.7.3
```